# How to use an altered Roslyn in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn

C# isn't enough for me, so I've taken advantage of the [newly-open sourced Roslyn](http://roslyn.codeplex.com/) to extend it, say by [modifying it to use French quotes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2014/04/03/taking-a-tour-of-roslyn.aspx).

But I don't want to build my newly-French-quoted files on the command line! I want Intellisense! I want a nice UI! In short, I want to get Visual Studio to use *my* Roslyn, not Microsoft's.

Can I do this yet? If so, *how*?

Comment: The "taking a tour of Roslyn" blog post you've linked to has a section that *discusses* how to get it working in VS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoted straight from [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2014/04/03/taking-a-tour-of-roslyn.aspx) in your question:

> ADVANCED USAGE
>
> It is also possible to update your copy of Visual Studio to use your
>   own built version of Roslyn (for example, to see how the IDE reacts to
>   your changes), but it’s slightly complicated:
>
> First of all, you’ll need to use the release fork, not the master
>   fork. This is because the compiler code is constantly changing in
>   reaction to feedback, and that includes changes to the APIs that are
>   used by the non-open IDE bits in the Roslyn preview in order to access
>   compiler information (until the APIs get locked down as we get closer
>   to completion). When these APIs change, the ability to communicate
>   between the two is lost. The release fork, however, accurately
>   reflects the state of the code at the time that the Roslyn preview was
>   snapped, and so is safe to use as a baseline for this sort of thing.
>   (You can see the fork on the Roslyn CodePlex site by choosing “Source
>   Code” and then opening the “Browsing changes in” dropdown – it’s
>   called “releases\build-preview.”)
>
> To switch to this fork in Git, you will need to execute the following
>   two commands from an appropriate Git prompt in your enlistment:
>
> > Git fetch
> >
> > Git checkout – track origin/releases/build-preview
>
> Your git repository will now have the contents of the
>   releases/build-preview branch.  Once you’ve done this, you can switch
>   back and forth between the branches using Git checkout master and git
>   checkout releases/build-preview. (Details on Git usage are beyond the
>   scope of this blog; see
>   http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches for more
>   information on branching in Git.)
>
> Second, you’ll need to disable Visual Studio’s strong-name assembly
>   checking for the relevant assemblies first. There’s a script to help
>   with that, which you can find checked into the source code at
>   Src/Tools/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Toolset.Open/Scripts/Prepare.bat.
>
> With all of that done, make your changes. Then, after building, ensure
>   that CompilerPackage is set as the startup project, and then
>   F5/Ctrl+F5 to launch a VS instance containing the changes.
>
> Please note that we will never accept pull requests for the release
>   fork – we need to keep it pristine and accurately reflecting the state
>   of the code relative to the Roslyn preview bits. Anything you actually
>   want considered for submission would need to be ported to a fork
>   created from the master first.

Interesting times ahead. Though I have a certain amount of trepidation about finding myself in a company where they use an entirely customised compiler to do awful, awful things. The gun to shoot yourself in the foot with has just been upgraded...

Comment: I'm going to upvote this, accept it, then go hide in shame. (I agree about the gun. The actual change I'm going to try this with is switching out all the keywords, just for giggles.)

Comment: @Rawling Never mind, sometimes in asking the question you stumble across the answer yourself. I just posted the answer for completeness as there wasn't really a valid reason to close the question.

Comment: @Rawling If you do that, you should [translate the keywords into Latin](http://search.cpan.org/~dconway/Lingua-Romana-Perligata-0.50/lib/Lingua/Romana/Perligata.pm) :-)

Comment: @svick I was going to go for something like Greek since I discovered you can quite happily use Unicode ಠ⌣ಠ

Comment: Great, now I'm a little scared of Roslyn too. I really don't want to see almost-but-not-quite-C# in my searches...